# Cannot call action for DialogModal jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I purchased a jquery plugin called `DialogModal`. There is a portion in the code where you can apply code to the action for the button. I have tried extensively to implement it using jquery but cannot.

Here is a link to the plugin: [Plugin Page](http://jobrangers.com/dialogmodaljqueryplugin/)

Here is the content produced by the plugin:

```
function getRangerModal()
{
    var content='<form id="rangerform" method="post" action="/en/ranger"> 
<div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="Firstname"> </div>
<br> <div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Lastname"> </div>
<br> <div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -33px;" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" value="" placeholder="Emailaddress"> </div>
<br> <div> <input type="password" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -77px;" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"> </div>
<br/><div><input type="password" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -77px;" name="retype_password" id="retype_password" value="" placeholder="Retype Password"> </form>'; 
var $popup=$(this).DialogModal({ 
theme :"default", 
style :"white", 
overlay :true, 
overlaycolor :"#000", 
overlayopacity :0.5, 
closeoverlay :true, 
closebutton :true, 
title :"Ranger Registration", 
content :content, 
width :400, radius :5, 
draggable :true, 
buttons :[{label:"Get Started", 
class:"button_class", 
action:function(){ $("#rangerform").submit(); }}, ]});
}
```

If you look at the $popup there is a portion called `action`. This is where the form submission content goes.

I have tried:

```
$("#rangerform").submit()
```

It does nothing.

Can someone assist please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED

With your updated info, I do see one issue, You have some issues with your code, extra ","

Here is some corrected code. Not sure if it's your issue but try it out and see

```
function getRangerModal()
{var content= '<form id="rangerform" method="post" action="/en/ranger"><div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="Firstname"> </div><br> <div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Lastname"> </div><br> <div> <input type="text" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -33px;" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" value="" placeholder="Emailaddress"> </div><br> <div> <input type="password" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -77px;" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"> </div><br/><div><input type="password" style="background-image: url(/images/icons.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right 11px;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;display: block;font-size: 15px;height: 40px;padding: 10px;width: 100% !important;background-position: right -77px;" name="retype_password" id="retype_password" value="" placeholder="Retype Password"> </form>'; 
var $popup=$(this).DialogModal({ 
theme :"default", 
style :"white", 
overlay :true, 
overlaycolor :"#000", 
overlayopacity :0.5, 
closeoverlay :true, 
closebutton :true, 
title :"Ranger Registration", 
content :content, 
width :400, radius :5, 
draggable :true, 
buttons :[{label:"Get Started", 
class:"button_class", 
action:function(){ $("#rangerform").submit(); }} ]});
}
```

Comment: Thats the problem. Its not processing. I dont know why its not working when I put the code inside the action area

Comment: I see. How are you calling $popup?

Comment: Im not. It loads when i click on a button that has the `getRangerModal()` onclick event.

Comment: So it works here: http://jobrangers.com/dialogmodaljqueryplugin/test.html however it does not work when you click on "GET STARTED" and it pulls up the modal window here: http://jobrangers.com/en/

Comment: Right off I see your test is using jQuery v2.1 and your page is using v1.9.1 with jQuery migrate 1.0.